# What does the hat symbol mean with reference to an undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

If I have a graph called $G$, what does $\widehat{G}$ mean? Is it a reference to a subgraph of $G$?

Here is the full statement, for clarity.

"Let $x_i$ be an endpoint of edge $e_i$ (in graph $G$)... Let $\widehat{G}_i$ be a graph formed by all nodes connected to $x_i$ in $G \setminus \{e_i\}$ and the corresponding edges of $G$."

Comment: Usally, maths books refer the reader all necessary notions at the end. Are you workin on a certain book?

Comment: I'm in a small book for building proofs, and it has no symbol reference :/

Comment: As far as I have ever seen, this is not a well-known, standard notation for anything. The definition *must* be in the book somewhere. What book are you using?

Comment: Building Proofs by David Stewart and Suely Oliveira. I've also added the full statement in the question above.

Comment: @apizzimenti: My advice ist to change the book. If it does not explain its notation, a book about mathematics is useless. Why should you invest time in a book if the authors did not invest time to compile it properly?

Comment: @Moritz it's the only notation in the book that I didn't understand, everything else is good. It's not a textbook, but more of a guide on how to build proofs. Also, I was able to clear it up. I happen to know both of the authors personally and Suely is my professor.

Comment: I changed $G$ \ {$e_i$} to $G\setminus\{e_i\}$.  That is proper MathJax usage.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\widehat{G}_i$ refers to a subgraph or clique of $G$ where all nodes are connected to endpoint $x_i$ of edge $e_i$, as told by one of the authors.